# bulk insert of Excel range to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

Would it be possible to BULK insert data from Excel name_defined_range or specified_range (like A1:C10) to SQL Server table before Excel file is saved? No saving file or prior exporting it to CSV.

Desired code would be:

```
INSERT INTO [tblTemp] ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4])

SELECT A.[Column1], A.[Column2], A.[Column3], A.[Column4]
FROM OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=MY_DEFINED_RANGE_IN_EXCEL;HDR=YES', 'select * from 
[MY_DEFINED_RANGE_IN_EXCEL]') AS A;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need top 10

```
INSERT INTO [tblTemp] ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4])
SELECT TOP 10 A.[Column1], A.[Column2], A.[Column3], A.[Column4]
FROM OPENROWSET 
('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=MY_DEFINED_RANGE_IN_EXCEL;HDR=YES', 'select * from 
[MY_DEFINED_RANGE_IN_EXCEL]') AS A;
```

Comment: What about the part MY_DEFINED_RANGE_IN_EXCEL. How to choose range only, not the entire sheet?